# Stop Outlook's "Reminder" from popping up

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We have Outlook Calendar open full screen on a display, but the reminder popup comes up and causes the task bar to show, and the box covers the screen. Is there a way to stop the pop-up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Outlook 2007, that would be:

- Tools
- Options...
- "Other" tab
- Advanced Options
- Reminder Options...
- Uncheck "Display the reminder"

[image]

Comment: Wish this could be updated for 2015's version 15.

Answer (score 16):

In Outlook 2015 this option is in a slightly different place, but is easily accessible via File → Options → Advanced Options → Reminders Heading.

[image: Outlook 2015 Reminder Options image]

Comment: The same is true for all versions 2010-2015.  Will have to see if that changes in upcoming releases.

Comment: Anyone know if there's a way to do this same thing on Outlook v16+ for Mac ?  I want to remove those reminders on my desktop but I want to keep default reminders so e.g. it shows up on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

For Outlook365 simply go to: File -> Options -> Advanced. There are some options for "Reminders". Just check the box "Automatically dismiss reminders for past calendar events".  Problem should be gone. Good luck.